# Why only set the precision if GL_ES is defined?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader, glsles

When writing code for a fragment shader, it starts as follows:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
```

Why does the `precision mediump float;` line have to depend on whether GL_ES was defined or not?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't "have to"; it simply does.

Desktop GL will ignore any `precision` declarations. So there's no need to `ifdef` around it.

That being said, if one wants to share GLSL code with very old versions of desktop GLSL (1.20 or before), then the `#ifdef` is useful, as such versions did not allow the `precision` declaration.